# CoreML frameworks generated different results from coremltools

Tags: ios, coreml

I have been developing image recognition app in ios 11 following the CoreML examples. However i notice that there is difference of the results when calling the model in ios, and the ones using coremltools in mac/python. I think the difference may lie on the image loading part. Python code use Pillow to load image, but xcode use CoreImage. I pasted the key codes as below. Hopefully somebody can help to point out the issue.

Also the input image is a 299*299 jpg. So should not any resizing happened in either of the implementation. Thank you.

### python codes

```
import coremltools  
from PIL import Image  
from keras.preprocessing import image  
import numpy as np  

IMG_PATH='./test.jpg'  
img = image.load_img(IMG_PATH)  
model=coremltools.models.MLModel("./Inceptionv3.mlmodel")  
res = model.predict({'image':img})
```

### ios codes

```
self.image = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];  
self.model = [[[Inceptionv3 alloc] init] model];  

VNCoreMLModel *m = [VNCoreMLModel modelForMLModel: self.model error:nil];  
VNCoreMLRequest *rq = [[VNCoreMLRequest alloc] initWithModel: m completionHandler: (VNRequestCompletionHandler) ^(VNRequest *request, NSError *error){  
    NSArray *results = [request.results copy];  
    NSString *top_results = @"";  
    for(int index = 0; index < kNumResults; index++)  
    {  
        VNClassificationObservation *res = ((VNClassificationObservation *)(results[index]));  
         NSString *tmp = [top_results stringByAppendingFormat: @"- %d %.4f %@\n ", index, res.confidence,res.identifier];  
         top_results = [tmp copy];  
    }  
    self.label_prob = [top_results copy];  
}];  

NSDictionary *d = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];  
NSArray *a = @[rq];  
VNImageRequestHandler *handler = [[VNImageRequestHandler alloc] initWithCIImage:self.image options:d];  

dispatch_queue_t myCustomQueue;  
myCustomQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyCustomQueue", NULL);  

dispatch_sync(myCustomQueue, ^{  
    [handler performRequests:a error:nil];  
});
```

The differences:

CoreML
top-5 military uniform: 0.254365 suit, suit of clothes: 0.198099 Windsor tie: 0.077577 bulletproof vest: 0.068461 comic book: 0.022226

coremltools
top-5 military uniform: 0.458214044571 bulletproof vest: 0.115854650736 suit, suit of clothes: 0.115854650736 Windsor tie: 0.0413092523813 pickelhaube: 0.0201325211674

Test image [original](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/ios/benchmark/data/grace_hopper.jpg) was pre-resized to 299*299 for testing.

Comment: *"However i notice that there is difference of the results..."* Can you elaborate on what this difference is?

Comment: #CoreML top-5
military uniform: 0.254365
suit, suit of clothes: 0.198099
Windsor tie: 0.077577
bulletproof vest: 0.068461
comic book: 0.022226

#coremltools top-5
military uniform: 0.458214044571
bulletproof vest: 0.115854650736
suit, suit of clothes: 0.115854650736
Windsor tie: 0.0413092523813
pickelhaube: 0.0201325211674

Test image is at [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/ios/benchmark/data/grace_hopper.jpg), which was pre-resized to 299*299 for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but with a model created with Xcode 10's CreateML tools. While CreateML gave me excellent precision and recall, I saw very degraded performance when using the model with the Vision framework.

By chance I discovered that I could get better performance if I converted the image to data before I passed it to the request handler. That is:

**Poor performance:**

`let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: myCGImage, options: [:])`

**Good performance:**

`let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(cgImage: myCGImage)!)!
let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(data: imageData, options: [:])`

Not sure why this is.

Comment: Yes, I am noticing the same thing and have bumping my head against the wall for days. Is this a bug?

Comment: I had much worse performance on iOS beta 3. My workaround no longer worked. I had to revert to 2. I'm going to try beta 4 today and see if it's resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and and I think it's connected with using different `Float` on macOS and IOS devices. Unfortunately, I did not find a way to solve the problem, because it seems to be a problem at the system level.